# android Bookview

Tags: java, android, view

I'd like to create something that works like a book (contents are displayed until it fills a page, and exceeding contents will be displayed in the next page), as a view for android. I extended a framelayout, added a listview and a linear layout with 2 buttons and a text (for the page number) on the constructor.

If it is just text, I can easily draw it using onDraw (instead of the list), get the text bounds and easily distribute any number of texts over pages and show only the ones associated with current page.

But I'd like my contents to be anything, so I decided to use a listview instead. How do I know how much space the contents will occupy as I add new contents? I don't mind if I have to wait for a certain call. You can assume that I know exactly what type of contents it will have on the creation or new content adding.

Example 1:
I have 10 icons and 10 textviews.
Line1: Icon1 Text1
Line2: Icon2 Text2
...
Line10: Icon10 Text10

Imagine each page can only fit to like 4 lines of icon/text.
Then first page has 4 lines, second page has 4 lines and third (last) page has 2 lines.

This is what I have now...:
[Book example](http://s17.postimage.org/lflihnjkv/exbook.png)

I must be able to add content on the fly (as an adapter or a function, I don't care).

Thank you very much

Comment: From what you've said I don't think ListView is a good choice. ListView is meant for long lists of data i.e. contacts application. I Would think that just extending one of the Layout Objects is what you'd want to do. Tough to say though with out a bit more info.

Comment: I could extend a layout object, which is pretty similar to drawing, but I'll still have 2 problems:
1) I still don't know the height of the contents to know how many of them in each page.
2) When I select a line, it's not like a Listview selection (which I'd like to see)
I'll add an example to the original post